# Employment with two companies at the same time

Tags: employment

I have joined in one MNC. But due to some issues I sent a resignation mail but I didn't get any response from them. At that time I got an offer in another company so I have joined the company without showing that previous employment. Now I am on the payroll of both the companies. Will this lead to any issues..?

Comment: If you have an advice of delivery for the resignation mail you have sent them at least it would proof they have knowledge of your resignation.

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: Iam working at India now

Answer (score 3):

Yes, knowingly being paid by a company which you're not performing work for is a problem. Ethically, you're stealing from them. The exact legal situation will depend on your jurisdiction, but almost every jurisdiction is going to frown on that kind of behaviour.

Get on the phone to HR at your "former" employer immediately and explain the situation. Hopefully you have a written record of your resignation mail.

Comment: And don't spend the money

Comment: I sent mail to manager he is not responding and I can't tell them like I have joined in another company because that time they may think I have absconded. But I don't want that situation and if I wait till their acceptance I will loose this opportunity..