# Cancellation of resignation after acceptance of resignation

Tags: software-industry, human-resources

I have resigned for my organization. They accepted my Resignation still I have one day left for my last working day.  Now can I withdraw my Resignation..?

Comment: Voting to close as "unclear what you're asking" because .... *why* are you asking (us)? Ask your manager.

Comment: Have you asked your employer if you can? I don't think you can arbitrarily declare you're not leaving now.

Comment: You probably can, then you'll probably be fired due to extreme incompetence.

Comment: @Nelson I have known at least one situation where somebody's personal circumstances have changed dramatically so that withdrawing a resignation was a reasonable course of action. And, for what it's worth, their employer kept them on.

Comment: Going through [another question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/77746/3192) you posted about a week ago, I imagine you have screwed up big time here. Give us the complete story, some of us may be able to help you get out of the mess.

Answer (score 6):

You can certainly walk into your manager's office and say "I want to keep working here". In any jurisdiction I'm aware of, it will then be up to your manager and others at your employer to decide whether to keep you on or not, but in almost every circumstance expect to be told "No, you resigned, you're out of here" - you're going to have to have a *really* good reason to convince your employer that you actually want to work there and you're not just going to leave in a few months, and I strongly suspect that you don't have that kind of reason; certainly "my new job doesn't look so good any more" isn't anywhere near good enough as a reason.

Comment: Even with a good reason, whether the manager decides to keep the employee on will depend on what the employer has done based  on the resignation. Some actions, especially personnel actions, are difficult to undo. They may have signed a contract with the OP's replacement, who will be starting work next week and has been assigned the OP's desk. Or they may have informed another employee of a promotion that would breach budget and/or headcount limits if they keep the OP.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan But it does no harm to try. Go in knowing that you might fail but there is a slim possibility.